# In which part of the ASP.NET life cycle does a page visually appear to the user?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, controls

I am currently working on an ASP.NET project and trying to figure out in which phase and method within the [life cycle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms178472(v=vs.140)) a page visually appears onto the screen.

Specifically this question is prompted by my investigation of an asp Login control used to open a new window.

Comment: The page lifecycle occurs serverside so anything that happens in the browser has nothing to do with it.  A new window is going to be opened via javascript.

Comment: It has less to do with the asp.net lifecycle and more to do with the HTML layout, css, and scripts being run.  Technically, the page appears (ie, the html is written to the browser) at the end of the Render stage, but depending on what you do in the code, it can appear earlier.. but even after rendering it may not appear in the browser based on the afore mentioned factors.

Comment: It is outside/after the ASP.NET lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

From the document you are linking:

> Rendering   Before rendering, view state is saved for the page and all controls. During the rendering stage, the page calls the Render
>   method for each control, providing a text writer that writes its
>   output to the OutputStream object of the page's Response property.
>
> Unload   The Unload event is raised after the page has been fully
>   rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded. At this
>   point, page properties such as Response and Request are unloaded and
>   cleanup is performed.

Maybe that would help...